# Использование route angular 4 в yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, angular-routing

При создание balloonContent в ymaps.Placemark создаётся div с элементами и ссылкой. Если сделать в нём написать ссылку такого вида

```
<a href="/project/1">К объекту</a>
```

То перезагружается вся страница а не отдельный компонент
Если же написать

```
`<a [routerLink]="['/project', 1">К объекту</a>`
```

То ссылка вообще не работает. Может кто подскажет как реализовать правильно роут, или может к компоненте в самом классе нужно зарегистрировать роуты которые будет отображены на странице